# Cannot cURL to NodeJS, but can access it from browser

Tags: php, node.js, curl

I can access my test Node site (`http://18.220.168.1:8888`) from a browser just fine.  However, when I attempt to cURL using PHP's cURL, I get:

```
Array
(
    [curl_error] => Failed to connect to 18.220.168.1 port 8888: Connection refused
    [error_number] => 7
)
```

My cURL setup is:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

// Temporary for testing self-signed sites
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: '.$data_type,                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data),
    'Public-Key: ' . $pub_key,
    'Private-Key: ' . $priv_key,
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $pub_key,)                                                                       
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

I am hosting on Amazon's EC2, and the ports are open (obviously since I can access it via my browser).  Any idea what I'm doing wrong here by chance?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I just tested with resteasy's tester, and it connected just fine.  So it has to be something either in the cURL request, or between the browsers.

Comment: what is `$url` set to?

Comment: The URL above for the node server: `http://18.220.168.1:8888`.
I've tried with and without the `http://`.

Comment: Looks like a firewall issue. On what machine are you running this code?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm running it from a test script on another AWS ec2 instance that I built to test API calls.  They both use the same security group, so both have port 8888 open.  However, I literally just tested with resteasy's tester, and it connected just fine.  So it has to be something either in the cURL request, or between the browsers.

Comment: With the error of "connection refused", I would agree with a firewall issue.  Try using tcping or tcptraceroute to port 8888 and verify it can really connect.

Comment: I feel so stupid.  I just realized I was doing this from a cPanel server that had CSF installed.  After adding this port to CSF, it worked.  I'll leave this up in case it helps anyone else who is having a brain fart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel so stupid. I just realized I was doing this from a cPanel server that had CSF installed. After adding this port to CSF, it worked. I'll leave this up in case it helps anyone else who is having a brain fart.